# union vs addrange in list, which on is fastest and good performance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

which on is do you think the best between two code below or you have another alternative that more efficient

First

```
List<int> g = new List<int>();
g.AddRange(listof1);
g.AddRange(listof2);
return g.GroupBy(a=>a)           
            .Select(root=>root.FirstOrDefault())
            .ToList();
```

Second

```
var rootIds = listof1.
            Union(listof2)
           .Select(rootId => rootId).ToList();

return rootIds;
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Get *BenchmarkDotNet* and do some tests on various inputs and solutions, and let us know

Comment: The `.Select(rootId => rootId)` is redundant as well.

Comment: For the first I'd suggest `Distinct` rather than `GroupBy` (note that, under the covers, it will act basically like `HashSet` so you may as well use `HashSet`).

Comment: Both of your examples include redundant/non-beneficial operations. Even ignoring the lack of appropriateness of this type of question for Stack Overflow, it is pointless to spend time comparing two different implementations when each of those implementations are themselves not written optimally. Your time would be better spent learning more about **macro** optimizations -- writing expressive code in a basic, correct manner -- than sweating the fine details. Crawl before you walk, walk before you run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It doesn't matter
2. Let's see :)

## Experiment

### Candidates

```
static int M1(List<int> l1, List<int> l2)
    {
        List<int> g = new List<int>();
        g.AddRange(l1);
        g.AddRange(l2);
        var x = g.GroupBy(a => a)
                    .Select(root => root.FirstOrDefault())
                    .ToList();
        return x.Count();
    }

    static int M2(List<int> l1, List<int> l2)
    {
        var x = l1
           .Union(l2)
           .Select(rootId => rootId).ToList();
        return x.Count();
    }

    static int M3(List<int> l1, List<int> l2)
    {
        var g = new HashSet<int>(l1);
        g.UnionWith(l2);
        return g.Count();
    }
```

### Results

```
100.00
0.057       0.038       0.017           res: 200,200,200
0.040       0.015       0.011           res: 200,200,200
0.055       0.023       0.009           res: 200,200,200
0.062       0.036       0.022           res: 200,200,200
0.055       0.023       0.027           res: 200,200,200
1,000,000.00
1788.493    513.422     292.815         res: 1999068,1999068,1999068
1795.416    591.142     453.076         res: 1999068,1999068,1999068
2540.099    529.801     303.729         res: 1999068,1999068,1999068
1797.251    527.849     428.672         res: 1999068,1999068,1999068
2008.561    527.680     501.997         res: 1999068,1999068,1999068
10,000,000.00
34458.838   6764.472    3679.255        res: 19906255,19906255,19906255
32756.011   8507.293    3875.931        res: 19906255,19906255,19906255
```

### Test code

```
public class Program
{
    static Random r = new Random(1);

    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Try(100);
        Try(1000000);
        Try(10000000);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Try(int i)
    {
        var l1 = Enumerable.Range(0, i).Select(i => r.Next(0, int.MaxValue)).ToList();
        var l2 = Enumerable.Range(0, i).Select(i => r.Next(0, int.MaxValue)).ToList();
        NapkinQualityCompareMeasureIt(i, 5, fs: new List<Func<int>> { () => M1(l1, l2), () => M2(l1, l2), () => M3(l1, l2) });
    }

    public static void NapkinQualityCompareMeasureIt<T>(int count, int howManyTimes, List<Func<T>> fs)
    {
        //This is good only for detecting significant differences
        Console.WriteLine(count.ToString("N"));
        for (int i = 0; i < howManyTimes; i++)
        {
            var metrics = fs.Select(f =>
            {
                var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                var r = f();
                return (Elapsed: sw.Elapsed, Result: r);
            });

            var res = string.Join(",", metrics.Select(m=>m.Result));
            var times = string.Join("", metrics.Select(m => $"{m.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("F3").PadRight(12)}"));
            Console.WriteLine($"{times}\tres: {res}");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

`HashSet<int>` is worth considering if you want a unique set of values:

```
var g = new HashSet<int>(listof1);
g.UnionWith(listof2);
```

The advantage of using `HashSet` is that it will be *impossible* for it to contain duplicate values - making code that uses `g` easier to read and reason about.